# Passing parameters to a class implementing ReportDataSourceService in JasperReports Server

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a *custom data source* at *JasperReports Server* and I need to pass some parameters to it beforehand report is filled.

I implemented a ***ReportDataSourceService*** but I cannot get how to pass parameters to it, in my application I need to pass two dates to filter values

```
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;

import com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.jasperreports.service.ReportDataSourceService;

public class ReportGeneratorService implements ReportDataSourceService {

   public void closeConnection() {
   }

   @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
   public void setReportParameterValues(Map parameters) {
       System.out.println(parameters);
       parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_DATA_SOURCE, 
       new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(ReportGenerator.collectionGenerator()));
   }
}
```

I'd like to pass the selected dates to `ReportGenerator.collectionGenerator()`

If it weren't possible to pass parameters to a custom data source, is creating my own **query executer** the way to go?